# Can AWS NLB be used to load balance requests to Read Replicas?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, load-balancing, mysql-replication

This [article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/scaling-mysql-tcp-load-balancing-nginx-plus-galera-cluster/) from Nginx describes how Nginx TCP load balancing can be used against MySQL cluster. In the first diagram, I would like to replace the Nginx LB with AWS NLB where, the MySQL cluster runs with Docker Compose.

Can you please point me to examples to implement this?

Comment: I guess it should work with an NLB... follow any NLB tutorial, but replace whatever the tutorial says to load balance to (e.g. 443 for https) with the MySQL ports. I haven't used an NLB in a while, but it's probably just setting up a target group then an NLB.